# Random memory appears when reading a file

Tags: c, file, fread

I've made a function that reads a file into the memory in C. But I'm having an issue with the code, random characters seem to appear at the end of the string. Even after I added '\0' at the end. I don't understand this at all since the whole file appears and I haven't malloc'd enough room for more characters, so there should be some kind of error if there are more chars? Anyway does anyone knows what's causing this?

```
char* LoadSourceFile(char* filename)
{
    int fileSize;
    char* buffer;
    struct stat handle;
    FILE* bestand;

    stat(filename, &handle);
    if (fopen_s(&bestand, filename, "r") != 0) {
        return NULL;
    }

    fileSize = handle.st_size;
    handle.st_size++;
    buffer = (char*)malloc(handle.st_size);
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        return buffer;
    }

    fread_s(buffer, handle.st_size, fileSize, 1, bestand);
    buffer[fileSize] = '\0';
    fclose(bestand);

    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you're reading past the end of the file, resulting in garbage output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the return from fread_s which is the number of bytes read to buffer. It could be less than expected.

```
bytes_read = fread_s(buffer, handle.st_size, fileSize, 1, bestand);
buffer[bytes_read] = '\0';
```

Edit: you would have to swap the count/size parameters to make what I said correct:

```
bytes_read = fread_s(buffer, handle.st_size, 1, fileSize, bestand);
buffer[bytes_read] = '\0';
```

Comment: The return value is 0 Though the text appears.

Comment: Also, if your default mode is 'text' (check fmode()), then some characters will be translated on read. This can result in the read being smaller than the file size reported by stat.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
fread_s(buffer, handle.st_size, fileSize, 1, bestand);
```

Should be

```
fread_s(buffer, handle.st_size, 1, fileSize, bestand);
```

According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh977173.aspx) the function `fread_s` accepts the following:

```
size_t fread_s(void *buffer,size_t bufferSize, size_t elementSize, size_t count, FILE *stream );
```

> buffer: Storage location for data.
>
> bufferSize: Size of the destination buffer in bytes.
>
> elementSize: **Size of the item to read in bytes.**
>
> count: Maximum number of items to be read.
>
> stream: Pointer to FILE structure.

You set the `elementSize` to `filesize` which means each element is `filesize` bytes, when it should be 1 byte.

Comment: @Ruben you're welcome, also don't increment `st_size` just add one when you allocate memory, this way it's less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Please strip out

```
handle.st_size++;
```

And insert

```
buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * ( handle.st_size + 1 ) );
```

And

```
fread_s(buffer, handle.st_size + 1, 1, handle.st_size, bestand);
```

Hope it helps :)